# Yii framework - Image Upload Using Rest Client

Tags: yii, image-upload, rest-client

I am new to Yii framework. In my project I have a controller called "UserController" and also have the associated model "User" and related View files created using Gii. On the "/user/create" page I am uploading user profile picture. Its all working fine from the create page.

However, when I try to upload the picture using REST Client (I am using Chrome - Advanced REST Client) the picture is unable to upload. If I upload all the other text (e.g email, firstname etc) details except the picture on the REST Client form then the user is created successfully but when I try to upload a picture along with the rest of the details then it fails. Actually, when I tried to debug then I came to know that while submitting the form with image from the REST client, it enters the "public function actionCreate()" function but does not go into the if(isset($_POST['User'])) { // code} condition. However, it works successfully if I upload image and details from the "/user/create" page.

Once again, I would like to say that the image gets uploaded successfully from the actual webpage created using Yii but the image cannot be uploaded using the REST client inspite of setting Content-type as "multipart/form-data".

Thanks
Prazi

Comment: You should inspect the differences of the headers between the webpage and the REST client which are sent to the webserver.

Comment: Could you please refer my answer Below is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676206/how-to-post-a-request-in-any-of-rest-clients-for-mime-type-as-multipart-related/36453223#36453223

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you REST client is sending data via GET (not POST) method?

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED:

I tried other chrome REST Client extension named "Postman" and was able to upload images from this client really easily. I think I was not able to use the "Advanced REST Client" to upload images but this "Postman REST Client" is really super cool and easy to use.

Following is the link for this REST client:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en