# How to POST a request in any of rest clients for mime type as "multipart/related"

Tags: rest, multipartform-data, multipart, multipartentity

I'm trying to do a POST request from any of rest client like (Advanced rest client, Postman etc) for posting a request with mime type "multipart/related" but none of rest client supports. So is there a way to quickly POST a request from any of rest clients or other alternate solutions?

Comment: have you tried jersey client ??

Comment: I have used Jersey framework for complete automation, but i'm looking for UI based Rest Client which would be plugins for firefox or Chrome like Advanced Rest Client or Postman or simple browser based clients where I can specify headers and upload the file and body content and quickly test the response from "multipart/related" mimetypes. I know Advanced Rest client support multipart/formdata.. But i'm looking for "multipart/related" type.           Here is the Advanced rest client I was mentioning : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not tried multipart/related, but multipart/mixed using jersey client.
Using Jersey client

Create a multipart request .. eg.

```
MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
 multiPart.bodyPart(....//
```

Then call the service like :

```
Client c = Client.create();
WebResource service = c.resource(Url);
ClientResponse response = service.type("multipart/mixed").header(headerkey,
            headervalue).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
```

Similarly try it for multipart/related. 
you have download jersery client jar from https://jersey.java.net/download.html

Comment: I have used Jersey framework for complete automation, but i'm looking for UI based Rest Client which would be plugins for firefox or Chrome like Advanced Rest Client or Postman or simple browser based clients where I can specify headers and upload the file and body content and quickly test the response from "multipart/related" mimetypes. I know Advanced Rest client support multipart/formdata.. But i'm looking for "multipart/related" type.    Here is the Advanced rest client I was mentioning : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Answer (score 0):

[image: Using Advance Rest Client Plugin in Chrome]

Attached image will help you, This way you can try using Advance Rest Client plugin in Chrome, and also don't forget to upload the file under the Files tab.